# nicematrix with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, nicematrix

Why don't the *nicematrix* and *fontspec* package play well together?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1-3]
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

When you comment out either the *fontspec* package or the *nicematrix* package (and the corresponding environment) the compilation runs fine.  As is, if you put in a NiceMatrix environment, it still compiles, but throws the error **LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.**

Comment: I have no such problem, compiling with xelatex as well as with lualatex. Is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: Interesting; I did update my installation before posting the question.   My system is a Mac running TeX Live 2019.  I can provide the log file if that would help.

Comment: Quite strange… And you have the error message with this very code?

Comment: Yep!  Here's the [link to the log file](https://pastebin.com/gEqnNQGq).  Apparently the error occurs immediately when loading the _nicematrix_ package.

Comment: I see you have the very latest version of nicematrix (3.2), whereas MiKTeX (my distribution) still has version 3.1. That's the only difference I notice. Maybe a problem with latest version. Just in case: try changing the loading order.

Comment: in a texlive updated a minute ago (including updates for nicematix and expl3) your example runs without error

Comment: correction it runs in luatex but fails in xetex, let me trace....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest update of the `nicematrix` package there is a zero width space

```
U+feff ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
```

at the start of line 21 before the `%` this is clearly an error, you should report to the package author.

You can save a local copy of the file, deleting the line

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
```

and it will run without error

Comment: I just mailed the author with a link to this post.

Comment: Awesome; I was just about to do that too.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I will post a corrected version of the package `nicematrix` on CTAN today.

Comment: I have posted on CTAN a corrected version (3.2a).

Comment: @F.Pantigny thanks!